# Like button counter is not changing

Tags: web, facebook-widgets

I have had users click the like button on my website but the counter remains at one.
I am using html5 version
I have also tried the iframe version with same results
My site is dvmark.com

Comment: Have you tried adding www. to the url you are passing?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, cleared my browser history and now it is showng the most updated number. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I cant find a clear description on the best way to implement the button. Please tell me the method you using